# How to bind src of an image from object?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Trying to render some images in a loop. I take the paths from an object.
Here is the object:

```
data () {
      return {
        logoRoutes: [
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/55spirit.png', 'alt': '55 Spirit logo' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/55aqua.png', 'alt': '55 Aqua logo' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/iam_different.png', 'alt': 'I\'m different logo' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/istiqlol.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/health.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/vitha_water.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/iam_fighter.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/horeca.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/kings_records.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/flytj.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/happy_smile.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/formula55.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/bima.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/dorob_fight.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/muzaffar.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/american_spaces.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/synergy.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/kmp.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/55startups.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/multikid.png', 'alt': '' },
          { 'link': '../assets/images/clients/55trade.png', 'alt': '' },
        ]
      }
    }
```

So, here's my code of rendering images:

```
<img :src="logoRoutes[0].link" :alt="logoRoutes[0].alt" />
```

Such a code generates the image with the path of:
[image]

But it says wrong path!
If I add the image with a static path it generates the path of:
[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the correct relative path of the image then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **require**

```
data () {
      return {
        logoRoutes: [
          { 'link': require('../assets/images/clients/55spirit.png'), 'alt': '55 Spirit logo' },
          { 'link': require('../assets/images/clients/55aqua.png'), 'alt': '55 Aqua logo' }
        ]
      }
    }
```